# R: Aggregating time series data returns NA

Tags: r, xts

I'm trying to aggreagate data by 5 minute means by using xts:

```
library(xts)
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/User/Documents/data.csv")
times <- data$Time
X <- as.POSIXct(times)
X <- as.xts(X)
DataTable <- period.apply(X, endpoints(X, "minutes", 5), mean)
```

The problem is, if print out "DataTable", it shows that the aggregation didn't work, the aggregation scores are empty (NA).

```
2016-08-28 21:26:32   NA
2016-08-28 21:29:05   NA
2016-08-28 21:30:57   NA
2016-08-28 21:34:31   NA
2016-08-28 21:35:22   NA
2016-08-28 21:37:31   NA
2016-08-28 21:40:15   NA
2016-08-28 21:43:59   NA
2016-08-28 21:48:01   NA
2016-08-28 21:48:58   NA
2016-08-28 21:49:14   NA
2016-08-28 22:40:45   NA
2016-08-28 23:40:45   NA
```

Here is the input file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/epkbk770ajksqnb/data.csv?dl=0

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you put `X` as the argument to aggregate rather than a numeric field (e.g. `T1` or `T2`).

```
   library(xts)
    mydata    <- read.csv("data.csv")
    times     <- mydata$Time
    X         <- as.POSIXct(times)
    X         <- as.xts(X)
    period.apply(mydata$T1, INDEX = endpoints(X, "minutes", 5), function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question you might help me with? How would I go about aggregating the ticks in to 5 minute intervals, would I need to add another column to my CSV file and fill it with "1" for each entery and then add them up for every 5 min interval?

Comment: @user3256536 You're very welcome. The ticks? You mean in a plot? I believe you'd just need to use the `breaks` option to set the tick marks.

Comment: The problem with using `cut` and `breaks` is that you can only set the breaks to a predetermined value such as hours or minutes, you cannot set it to 5 minutes.

My bad, yes you can... `DataTable <- table(cut(data, breaks="5 mins"))` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your xts object doesn't have any data because you created it with times only. Your first block of code is equivalent to:

```
library(xts)
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/User/Documents/data.csv")
X <- as.xts(as.POSIXct(data$Time))
```

Your `period.apply` call works just fine if you create an xts object with data.

```
X <- as.xts(read.zoo("C:/Users/User/Documents/data.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE))
DataTable <- period.apply(X, endpoints(X, "minutes", 5), mean)
```