# Convert sequential numeric data into time format in R

Tags: r, time, ggplot2

Let's say I have a dataframe with a column t which consists of cumulative time differences of seconds from the first point of the dataset with a frequency of 10 Hz. How can I convert this into R time in Min:Second format, so that it will show up in ggplots. I will only show every 5 minutes a tick on the x axis, and the corrsponding time in 00:00, 05:00, 10:00...etc.

Example:

```
# t columns is in seconds, thus 2000 seconds makes 33.33 minutes
# Last tick value on the x axis I will show is 30:00
d1 = 10 + runif(n = 5000)
d2 = 20 + runif(n = 5000)
d3 = 30 + runif(n = 5000)
d4 = 40 + runif(n = 5001)
d = c(d1,d2,d3,d4)
t = seq(0, 2000, by = 0.1)
DF = data.frame(t = t, d = d)
ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = t, y = d)) + geom_line()
```

Thank you,

Comment: `lubridate` is the easiest way to do the conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to convert values to `POSIXct` class with dummy-date via `difftime`.

```
DF$min_sec <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01") + as.difftime(DF$t, unit="secs")

ggplot(DF, aes(x = min_sec, y = d)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "5 min", date_labels = "%M:%S", minor_breaks=NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Spot on. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
DF = data.frame(t = seq(0, 2000, by = 0.1), data = runif(n = 20001))

DF$t <- lubridate::ms(DF$t)
```

For the second part you might want to check out this question/answer (including comments) from a few hours ago. He asked the exact same question.

[R: Aggregating time series data returns NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190964/r-aggregating-time-series-data-returns-na/39191378#39191378)

I aggregated his data every 5 minutes like this:

```
library(xts)
    mydata    <- read.csv("data.csv")
    times     <- mydata$Time
    X         <- as.POSIXct(times)
    X         <- as.xts(X)
    period.apply(mydata$T1, INDEX = endpoints(X, "minutes", 5), function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T))
```

then he said he was plotting it like this:

```
DataTable <- table(cut(data, breaks="5 mins"))
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the example. Although it did convert t column to some sort of time, I could not plot it. I did not understand the other question and answer. By the way to make the example nicer I have changed it a bit.

Comment: I realized ms does not do what I want. The t values become like "999M 7S" "999M 8S" "999M 9S", which i wrong, and also not what I want. The data is 33 minutes in length.

Comment: @Sean Reddy; Your code can't convert data correctly.

Comment: @SeanReddy; Hum, my comment was about your first code block.  At least on my environment, original `DF$t` are 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ~, but `ms(DF$t)` returns 0s, 1s, 2s, 3s, ~.